# Add values dynamically in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently learning MySQL and trying to find out how to code dynamically for input values.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE add_user(
IN username VARCHAR (16),
IN pass VARCHAR (255),
IN email VARCHAR(255),
IN fname VARCHAR (32),
IN lname VARCHAR (32),
IN age INT )

BEGIN

INSERT INTO users (username, pass, email, fname, lname, age)

VALUES (@username, @pass, @email, @fname, @lname, @age);

INSERT INTO usershobbies (u_id, h_id)

VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '1');

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

When I call the procedure and insert values, I get an error message:

```
call add_user('bugsbunny', 'Carrot1000', 'bugs@bunny.com', 'Bugs','Bunny', '80');
```

> #1054 - Unknown column 'age' in 'field list'

I appreciate any feedback. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is telling you that there is no column `age` in table `users`. You would need to check the definition of your table (which you did not provide in your question).

Also, when using in/out parameters in MySQL, you should not prefix them with `@`. I like to give them a string prefix (like `p_`) do disambiguate from other litteral strings such as column names :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_user(
    IN p_username VARCHAR (16),
    IN p_pass VARCHAR (255),
    IN p_email VARCHAR(255),
    IN p_fname VARCHAR (32),
    IN p_lname VARCHAR (32),
    IN p_age INT 
)    
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO users (username, pass, email, fname, lname)
        VALUES (p_username, p_pass, p_email, p_fname, p_lname);

    INSERT INTO usershobbies (u_id, h_id) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '1');
END;
```

Comment: I did check if it exists. It does, and it holds different values already for the already existing users.
But I've redone my tables from scratch and tested again, and it worked...
Thank you very much for your guidance about the parameters!